# 2 methods to calcuate Sx(t)

Tags: actuarial-science

I just began studying for the SOA LTAM exam.  There are 2 methods shown in the text for calculating $S_x(t)$, the survival function for a life age x to survive until at least time t:

Method 1:
$S_x(t) = \frac{S_o(x+t)}{S_o(x)}$

Method 2:
$$Sx(t) e^{\int_{0}^{t}{Ux+s} \space ds}$$, 
where $$Ux+s = 
\frac{\frac{d}{ds} (S_o(x+s))}{S_o(x+s)}$$

For the function $S_o(x) = (1-\frac{x}{120})^{\frac{1}{6}}$

applying method 1:
$$\frac{S_o(x+t)}{S_o(x)}= \frac{(1-\frac{(x+t)}{120})^{\frac{1}{6}}}{(1-\frac{x}{120})^{\frac{1}{6}}} = (1-\frac{t}{(120-x)})^{\frac{1}{6}}$$

applying method 2, I get $$Sx(t) =(1-\frac{t}{(120-x)})^{\frac{120}{(720-x)}}$$

so they only give the same result when $x=0$, but I thought they should be the same result for all $x$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please learn use of Mathjax for future questions. Link here:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ok thanks for the link and the edits!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I did not calculate $u_{x+s}$ correctly.  The two approaches of course do produce the same result: $S_x(t) = (1-\frac {t}{(120-x)})^\frac 1 6 $.

Method 2 should have read:
$S_x(t) = e^-{\int_{0}^{t}{u_{x+s}} \space ds}$

and the formula for $u_{x+s}$ should have read:  $u_{x+s} = \frac {-\frac d {ds} S_x(x+s)} {S_ 0(x)}$

I had incorrectly calculated $u_{x+s} = \frac {-\frac d {ds} S_x(s)} {S_ x(s)} = -\frac d {ds} \space ln \space S_x(s)$